# React-native-fs : How to use readDir recursively using .map()?

Tags: react-native, array.prototype.map, react-native-fs

I tried to get all the files and directories available in a folder using react-native-fs.

I created a function to get all the files and directories recursively in a folder, I call this function this way :

```js
const data = await scanDir(path);
```

I first tried using the **.map()** function but my function **return only some elements** :

```js
async function scanDir(pathOfDirToScan, data = {directory: [], files: []}) {
  const readedFilesAndDir = await FS.readDir(pathOfDirToScan);

  Object.keys(readedFilesAndDir).map(async key => {
    if (readedFilesAndDir[key].isDirectory()) {
      const directoryPath = pathOfDirToScan + '/' + readedFilesAndDir[key].name;
      data.directory.push(directoryPath);
      data = await scanDir(directoryPath, data);
    } else {
      data.files.push(pathOfDirToScan + '/' + readedFilesAndDir[key].name);
    }
  });

  return data;
}
```

It seems my function return the data after the first time map is executed, but the function continue after that.

I then tried with a **for loop** and it **works as intended** :

```js
async function scanDir(pathOfDirToScan, data = {directory: [], files: []}) {
  const readedFilesAndDir = await FS.readDir(pathOfDirToScan);

  for (let i = 0; i < readedFilesAndDir.length; i++) {
    if (readedFilesAndDir[i].isDirectory()) {
      const directoryPath = pathOfDirToScan + '/' + readedFilesAndDir[i].name;
      data.directory.push(directoryPath);
      data = await scanDir(directoryPath, data);
    } else {
      data.files.push(pathOfDirToScan + '/' + readedFilesAndDir[i].name);
    }
  }

  return data;
}
```

What should I do to make the function properly works using .map() ?

Answer (score 0):

The `FS.readDir(dirpath)` returns an array of objects as per [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs). `Object.keys(obj)` is not required for iteration in that case, just `readedFilesAndDir.map()` will do your task.

Copy and pasted your own code with some corrections. Hope, it helps:

```js
async function scanDir(pathOfDirToScan, data = {directory: [], files: []}) {
  const readedFilesAndDir = await FS.readDir(pathOfDirToScan);

  readedFilesAndDir.map(async eachItem=> {
    if (eachItem.isDirectory()) {
      const directoryPath = pathOfDirToScan + '/' + eachItem.name;
      data.directory.push(directoryPath);
      data = await scanDir(directoryPath, data);
    } else {
      data.files.push(pathOfDirToScan + '/' + eachItem.name);
    }
  });

  return data;
}
```